# Error in VB: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in language.exe

Tags: vb.net

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in language.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

here is the code where the error is:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles         RichTextBox1.KeyDown
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        i = i + 1
        Dim t As String = RichTextBox1.Lines(i).ToString()
        ListBox1.Items.Add(t)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Arrays in NET starts at index zero. The first line of the RichTextBox is at index zero not one.

Comment: Clearly you're trying to retrieve a line from the RichTextBox that doesn't exist, just exactly like the error message is telling you. Learn to actually *read the words* in the error message - they actually have useful information in them. (You should also learn to use the debugger; even if you did not read the error message, the debugger would have shown you exactly what the problem was and where it was happening.)

Comment: As the guys above said, arrays start at zero, plus your code is not exactly clear, what are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to put every line of text that is entered into a rtb into

Comment: a listbox sorry about the space

Comment: it would be better to use For Each instead, i'll put up an example for you in a minute.

Comment: `i` is not going to increment like you seem to think it will.  `Dim i...` means it starts at zero every time a key is pressed, which is a very odd place to read lines - do you really want that code to run **every time** a key is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    Dim index As Integer = RichTextBox1.SelectionStart
    Dim line As Integer = RichTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(RichTextBox1.Lines(line).ToString())
End If
```

Comment: that doesnt work because that just adds the whole thing over and over again i just want it to be done line by line

Comment: Ok, so let me get this right, you want it when you press enter the line above is added to the listbox?